# Passing parameters to svelte function

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm new to Svelte so forgive me if this is obvious, but I've tried solutions I've seen on other posts and none seem to have worked.

The function is called as follows: 
`<div on:mouseover={() => exampleFunction("1")}>`

and it is written in the JS as:

```
function exampleFunction(id){
document.getElementById(`item-${id}`).classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

The 'id' shows as undefined in the function, so I figured the error is where it's being passed from.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: show your exampleFunction here in the question

Comment: ive tried this here ..it works perfectly https://svelte.dev/examples#reactive-assignments

Comment: I don't see any parameters passed to the function in that example though? Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Like i edited let me show you in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this screenshot , its working

Run it live here:https://svelte.dev/repl/501e5d478bbe4bc5a5e9f6a67523d080?version=3.16.0

[image]

Code:

```
<script>

    function exampleFunction(id){
  console.log("Before removing hidden",document.getElementById(`item-${id}`).classList);
        document.getElementById(`item-${id}`).classList.remove('hidden');
      console.log("After removing hidden",document.getElementById(`item-${id}`).classList); 
  }
</script>

<button on:mouseover={() => exampleFunction("1")}>
    Hover here
</button>
<span id="item-1" class="active hidden"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful - it does indeed work! My original script was slightly differnet so now I've fixed that and it's all good, so thanks again.

Comment: Welcome bruh...!